# Is there a way with MySQL to include the time a query takes in the results table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to include the time it takes to run a query as part of the output. Is this possible?

For example, this query:

```
mysql> SELECT count(*) AS NumberOfUsers FROM mdl_user;
+---------------+
| NumberOfUsers |
+---------------+
|          5741 |
+---------------+
1 row in set (0.16 sec)
```

I want to run it so that the "0.16 sec" value appears in a second column. Something like:

```
mysql> SELECT
  count(*) AS NumberOfUsers
  , QUERY_TIME() AS TimeToRunQuery
 FROM mdl_user;
+---------------+----------------+
| NumberOfUsers | TimeToRunQuery |
+---------------+----------------+
|          5741 |       0.16 sec |
+---------------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.16 sec)
```

Comment: Time taken isn't worth it, even if it were possible.  There's load on the server, and the network between, and then the application that factors into the time taken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, sorry. If you're interested just for informational purposes, you can have your script simply time the query by recording the time when the query is sent and subtracting that from the time when the query completes.

In PHP, it'd look something like this:

```
$start_time = microtime();
execute_query();
$end_time = microtime() - $start_time; // execution time in microseconds
```

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for a mysql-client-only answer. I'll figure something out with the CLI "time" command.